# Is there any difference between DATE_SUB() and using arithmetic operators for datetime calculation?

Tags: mysql, datetime, function, date, math

After I have seen a lot of questions here using the `DATE_SUB()` or `DATE_ADD()` functions instead of the arithmetic operators `+` or `-`, I was wondering if there was any difference:

Quote from the [MySQL-manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

> Date arithmetic also can be performed using INTERVAL together with the + or
>   - operator:
>
> ```
> date + INTERVAL expr unit
> date - INTERVAL expr unit
> ```

So basically, these two statements return the same result:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

and

```
SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY;
```

Now my question:

**Is there any difference between `DATE_SUB()` and using the `-` operator in MySQL?** (besides readability?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MySQL documentation for DATE_ADD (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) explicitly states that you may do date arithmetic with the + and - operators.

> > Date arithmetic also can be performed using INTERVAL together with the + or - operator:
> >
> > date + INTERVAL expr unit
> >
> > date - INTERVAL expr unit

Given that it's endorsed by the docs, I think any difference is stylistic. I personally think the +/- is easier to read (after all, you don't use INT_ADD(...) or DOUBLE_ADD(...) to manipulate numeric values, so why dates?). Others might have their own reasons for liking DATE_ADD and DATE_SUB, and that's fine too. Just pick something and stick with it.

Jemiah

Answer (score 3):

For me, it is a matter of experience. After dealing with multiple editors, libraries, and tools that manipulate databases, I've learned not to trust the "+" and "-" operators as much as I trust DATE_SUB(). It's a lot less likely that something is going to be accidentally broken as part of the next software upgrade with DATE_SUB(), when compared to using +/-

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit? In which case would an editor break the sql syntax?

Comment: For example, in cases in which the parser is broken - with the SQL editor accepting invalid SQL as valid, or indicating that valid SQL is not valid and refusing to accept it.