# MySQL: Delete all rows older than 20 Hours

Tags: mysql

I have a timestamp field in my table. How do I delete records older than 20 hours old?

My query is : `DELETE FROM tickets WHERE timestamp < (NOW() - INTERVAL 20 HOUR)`

Question: Is above query is correct?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: First `SELECT * FROM` then `DELETE FROM` if the rows look correct.

Comment: Nevermind found this: [Difference between date_sub and arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177100/is-there-any-difference-between-date-sub-and-using-arithmetic-operators-for-da)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your `delete` query is correct.