# Postgres ERROR: syntax error at or near "HOUR"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to delete all records into Postgress table and leave only records which were created last 1 hour. I tried this:

```
DELETE FROM common.orders WHERE created_at < (NOW(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR);
```

But I get error:

```
[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "HOUR"
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: I think this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043431/mysql-delete-all-rows-older-than-20-hours will answer your query

Comment: *But I get error: [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "HOUR"* 42601 is not documented SQLSTATE in MySQL. Moreover, there is no 42601 number on dev.mysql.com at all... And MySQL never uses double quote chars for keywords wrapping in its error messages.

Comment: I saw my mistake. The database is Postgress. I will update my question.

Answer (score 2):

Move the minus outside of the `INTERVAL` clause.  Also, the comma after `NOW()` should be removed as well, and the value for the unit needs to be specified in single quotes

```sql
DELETE FROM common.orders WHERE created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL '1 HOUR';
```

Comment: Just a note, the ANSI SQL syntax is `INTERVAL '1' HOUR`.